# How to disable linear interpolation / smoothing / anti-aliasing when drawing an image in Cairo?

Tags: cairo, pycairo

I want to draw a low-resolution image onto another surface in Cairo with upscaling. For instance, I have a 2x3 image which looks like this when zoomed in:

[image]

Drawing this image onto another surface with a zoom level of 10 results in:

[image]

The rendering code closely follows [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7145780/1804173), i.e., all surface/context settings are at default. Apparently, Cairo applies some interpolation by default. What I want is to keep the blocky/pixelated look of the original image.

How can I control the type of interpolation in Cairo? In other libraries, there are commonly options to set `interpolation` to from `cubic` over `linear` to `nearest`. Is there an equivalent in Cairo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like `cairo_pattern_set_filter(cairo_get_source(cr), CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST);`. This call would be done after `cairo_set_source_surface()`.